# What if/ should I use threading to update global variables.[pythonic way]

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function to update a global/class variable.
So, What should care after regularly invoke such function as subthread?(in asynchronous way)

Or, any suggestions to avoid using this pattern? (the pathonic way)

```
import time
import threading

# through global variable or class variable
_a = 123


def update_a():        # may be called more than once
    "slow updating process"
    time.sleep(3)
    global _a
    _a += 10
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(_a)
    th = threading.Thread(target=update_a)
    th.setDaemon(True)
    th.start()
    print(_a)
    # updating aynchrounously
    time.sleep(5)
    print(_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates that [addition is not threadsafe](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm) (See Josiah Carlson' comment. `effbot.org` seems to be down right now; you can check out an archived version of the page through the [wayback machine here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130408080524/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm).):

```
import threading
x = 0
def foo():
    global x
    for i in xrange(1000000):
        x += 1
threads = [threading.Thread(target=foo), threading.Thread(target=foo)]
for t in threads:
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print(x)
```

yields some number less than 2000000. This shows that some calls to `x += 1` did not properly update the variable.

The solution is to protect assignment to your global variable with a lock:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
def safe_foo():
    global x
    for i in xrange(1000000):
        with lock:
            x += 1

x = 0
threads = [threading.Thread(target=safe_foo), threading.Thread(target=safe_foo)]
for t in threads:
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print(x)
```

yields 2000000.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, threads are a thing to avoid in Python altogether, but if you really want to, I'd do it like this. First, create a thread-safe object with a [lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects):

```
class ThreadSafeValue(object):
    def __init__(self, init):
        self._value = init
        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def atomic_update(self, func):
        with self._lock:
            self._value = func(self._value)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

then I'd pass that to the thread target function:

```
def update(val):
    time.sleep(3)
    val.atomic_update(lambda v: v + 10)

def main():
    a = ThreadSaveValue(123)
    print a.value
    th = threading.Thread(target=update, args=(a,))
    th.daemon = True
    th.start()
    print a.value
    th.join()
    print a.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That way you will avoid global variables and ensure the thread-safety.